# MergeAdapter with AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm want to load a MergeAdapter with a Loader. I add adapters to the MergeAdapter on onLoadFinihed callback but the ListView appears empty. I noticed that the getview method of the custom adapter is not called.

I run the same code with the same custom adapter and works well, but I need to add headers to the ListView.

MergeAdapter works with Loaders?

Some code:

I set te adapter:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setEmptyText(getString(R.string.raceList_empty));

    mAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
}
```

And then on onLoadFinihed:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Race>> loader, List<Race> data) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.race_header_row, null);
    mAdapter.addView(headerView, true);

    RaceAdapter activeAdapter = new RaceAdapter(getActivity());

    activeAdapter.setData(data);

    mAdapter.addAdapter(activeAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MergeAdapter works with Loaders?

Not the way that you are doing it. Quoting [the current edition of the documentation's "Timing" section](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge#timing):

> You must pour the contents into the MergeAdapter before calling setListAdapter() to associate the MergeAdapter with a ListView. This limitation is required because Android only calls getViewTypeCount() once, and adding more views or adapters adds more view types.

Comment: I add the views and adapters on "onActivityCreated" method and then I set data on "onLoadFinished". Thanks!!!